# Ridge Regression B Coefficients Calculation

Tags: python, statistics, regression

I am trying to calculate the ridge regression B coefficients through this formula in Python:

(X^T * X + λ*I)^(−1) + X^T * y

where:
X^T = X transposed
X^(-1) = inverse matrix of X

Question: What shape should the identity matrix (I) take? X.shape or y.shape?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`I` should be the shape of `X'X`, only then will matrix addition be permitted. X is generally of shape `[n,m]`, where n is the number of instances (rows) and m is the number of features (columns). Therefore, `X'X` is of shape `[m,m]`, which should be the shape of `I`.

Also note that often when we formulate `X`, we have a column for the bias terms. Meaning, you might have `m` features, but `X` will have `m+1` columns, including the bias.

Hope this helps.